# Remove unicode control characters in redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I want to convert this javascript to redshift sql:

`str.replace(/[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/g, " ");`

I tried this, and a bunch of variations, at one point it was removing the ascii characters and keeping the control ones :)

`REGEXP_REPLACE(str, $$[\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]$$, ' ', 1, 'p')`

I was gonna just try to paste in the actual control characters themselves but I can't seem to generate 0000 to copy it... not sure it would work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This has been long-running topic w/ Redshift - handling regexp strings appropriately.  It's been a while since I push then on this so take this as possibly dated information.

First I've had inconsistent results with unicode and hex representations of character ranges in regexp strings (\u or \x).

Second ascii 0000 is illegal in Redshift strings so you don't need to worry about that.

Third ranging characters outside of the base ascii characters seems to not work well.  So you are better off doing NOT ASCII ranges.

Try this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^'||chr(32)||'-'||chr(127)||']', ' ')
```

Comment: Except I live in the real world where China actually exists...

Comment: Then I pass the baton to you, oh most peevish one, to continue the battle with Redshift to better implement non-ascii regexp functionality.  I've done my done my time and made my best efforts on this front over many year.  Your turn.

Comment: Eh I just shoved the regex into the lambda I'm calling from redshift :)